# query to get below result PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have data in a database as given below.

```
id | tid  |                   created_at
---+------+---------------------------------------------------------
1  | 45562|             12/02/2017 9:35
---+------+---------------------------------------------------------
2  | 5422 |             12/02/2017 12:54
---+------+---------------------------------------------------------
3  | 7422 |             12/02/2017 9:36
```

query to get records created between 9 to 10 time

Comment: whats the problem.

Comment: What is the output you expect?

Comment: Cast a timestamp to `time` to discard the date part.

Comment: I want the result as id 1 and 3 because it occurs between 9 to 10 am also I want these rows between a specified date range

i.e time window between specified date range and time

Comment: list all the records created between time 9 am to 10 am with date range of 20-05-2019 to 20-06-2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you need the rows that is having time range between `9` and `10`. If so, you can use the below query.

```
SELECT *
FROM Your_table
WHERE EXTRACT(HOUR FROM created_at)>=9 and EXTRACT(HOUR FROM created_at) <10
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=c0b9d290cdd37f1b0507266df61a8119)

OUTPUT:

```
+----+-------+---------------------+
| id | tid   | created_at          |
+----+-------+---------------------+
| 1  | 45562 | 2017-02-12 09:35:00 |
+----+-------+---------------------+
| 3  | 7422  | 2017-02-12 09:36:00 |
+----+-------+---------------------+
```

Update:

You can use the below query to select the rows for specific date range.Change your date range accordingly

```
SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE created_at BETWEEN '2017-02-01'::date AND '2017-02-10'::date AND
(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM created_at)>=9 and EXTRACT(HOUR FROM created_at) <10)
```

Comment: It works but what if I want to select a date range as well 
I wrote
SELECT id
FROM tickets
WHERE created_at between '2020-01-23' and '2020-01-25' and EXTRACT(HOUR FROM created_at)>=9 and EXTRACT(HOUR FROM created_at) < 10;

and it results 0 row;

Comment: @testertest, Please check the updated query in my answer.

Comment: If this works as expected, I would appreciate if you can mark the answer as correct. Thanks! @testertest CHECK THIS [HOW DO I ACCEPT AN ANSWER](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)